# If two functions are equal on a uncountable set then they are equal

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $K\subset \mathbb C$ be a bounded set.Let $f,g $ are entire functions over $\mathbb C$ .It is given that $f|_K=g|_K$.

If $K$ is uncountable prove that $f=g$ on $\mathbb C$ .

**My try**:

Let $h=f-g$ since $K$  is uncountable then we can extract a sequence from $K$ say $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)=g(x_n)$ .If I can prove that $x_n$ has a limit point in $K$ then by Identity theorem $g=f$ on $\mathbb C$ .

Is the approach right ?How to show that $x_n$ has a limit point in $K$?

Comment: The approach is not much wrong. But you need to show that $K$ has an accumulation point _before_ taking the sequence (for once you have the sequence, it could be that the sequence has no limit point).

Comment: will you please suggest the edits sir @DanielFischer

Comment: Once you know that $K \cap \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\}$ is infinite for some suitable $R$, can you conclude?

Comment: I mean conclude what?

Comment: Conclude the assertion ($f \equiv g$); finish the argument. Say you have found an $R\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $K\cap \{z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\}$ is infinite. Can you deduce $f \equiv g$ from that?

Comment: @DanielFischer Since $K$ is bounded, it should be OK to choose the sequence $(x_n)$ first, and then pass to a convergent subsequence.  The limit might not be in $K$, but that does not harm, since the given functions are entire.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh, duh. Completely overlooked that condition.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is made harder by having more hypotheses than are needed. Given that $K$ is bounded, one needs only that it's infinite, not that it's uncountable.  On the other hand, given that it's uncountable, one doesn't need boundedness.

Comment: @learnmore Since there is the assumption that $K$ is bounded, see Andreas Blass' comment. My points are relevant only without that assumption. The conclusion holds whenever $K$ is uncountable, bounded or not. In the unbounded case, you need a little extra argument.

Answer (score 0):

K has an infinite countable dense set A={x_1,...}. If A does not cluster in K then for each point in A it has a neighborhood which meets K in only point. If we unite these we get a countable set equal to K, a contradiction. Thus there is an accumulation point in K. Now we use the identity theorem to complete the proof.